# How to use interface name instead of IP addresss on IPFW?

Tags: freebsd, openbsd, ipfw

```
add 04000 allow IP from 192.168.1.10 to ca-vancouver.privateinternetaccess.com keep-state
```

I want to change to epair0b because I want to avoid hardcoded IP address and I would like to use DHCP instead

So I changed to

```
add 04000 allow IP from epair0b to ca-vancouver.privateinternetaccess.com keep-state
```

And got the error

````
Line 6: hostname ```epair0b'' unknow
````

Is there a way to use the interface name or "the machine" on IPFW?

In other words, I want to avoid the use of hardcoded IP Address on my rules.

Thanks!

Comment: disclaimer: never tested. in https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html#idp69473656 there are examples. Of course you can't use `from interface` since the expected parameter is an IP address. check in the examples the `via` parameter instead (`via interface`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [`ipfw` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ipfw(8)),

```
me     Matches any IP address configured on an interface in the system.
```

```
add 04000 allow IP from me to ca-vancouver.privateinternetaccess.com keep-state
```

Answer (score 1):

The DHCP daemon could update your `/etc/hosts` file and set the local IP next to the hostname. This way you could use the hostname which would resolve to the current IP.

Type `hostname` to get your hostname.

Check the manpages of the DHCP daemon how they implement it. It could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$IFACE" = lo ]; then
    exit 0
fi

SHORT_HOST=`hostname`

# Remove current line with hostname at the end of line
sed -i '/'$SHORT_HOST'$/ d' /etc/hosts

ipaddr=$(ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}')
echo "$ipaddr $SHORT_HOST" >>/etc/hosts
```